# How to make a function for multiple jQuery actions without writing so much code?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

Let me explain,

I'm making a page about everything I'm learning in PHP. I also want to add a great deal of interactivity to this page. For example, I want to add a button displaying more information (Hidden) and have a jQuery slide down do the job. However, I don't want to line a million and one lines of code making the file obsolete.

I'm trying to make a web page that has my buttons performing the same actions in different paragraphs. I want to know if there's a way to implement a function in order to not type 1000 lines of code to keep up with all the buttons and paragraphs. Please help me, thank you in advance.

```
<?php


$line_break = '<b><span class="bg-light m-0 p-0">/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\/\ </span></b>';

?>


<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- LOGO -->
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="../imgs/logotree.png" />
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="../js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>

    <title>Treehoose</title>
  </head>
  <body class="bg-secondary">





<div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-light text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4 ">5/<span class="text-primary">23</span>/18</h1>
  <p class="lead text-success p-0 m-0">PHP Arrays & Control Structures</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p><b>Loops & Structuring </b></p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" id="information_1" role="button">Show More Information</a>
  </p>
  <p id="extra_1" style="display: hidden;">extra information that may be less important, yet necesary</p>
</div>


<?php echo $line_break;?>


<div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-light text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4 ">5/<span class="text-primary">24</span>/18</h1>
  <p class="lead text-success p-0 m-0">PHP Arrays & Control Structures</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p><b>Loops & Structuring </b></p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" id="information_1" role="button">Show More Information</a>
  </p>
  <p id="extra_1" style="display: hidden;">extra information that may be less important, yet necesary</p>
</div>


<?php echo $line_break;?>

       <!-- jQuery -->

       <script>
         $(document).ready(function(){
          $('#extra_1').hide();
    $("#information_1").dblclick(function(){
        $("#extra_1").slideUp();
    });
    $("#information_1").click(function(){
        $("#extra_1").slideDown();
    });
});

       </script>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.0/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-cs/chFZiN24E4KMATLdqdvsezGxaGsi4hLGOzlXwp5UZB1LY//20VyM2taTB4QvJ" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-uefMccjFJAIv6A+rW+L4AHf99KvxDjWSu1z9VI8SKNVmz4sk7buKt/6v9KI65qnm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can use the jquery selector on class (instead of id) and apply the same behavior to multiple elements at once ([example](https://jsfiddle.net/hLyb147j/2/))

Comment: You have multiple elements with the id `information_1` and `extra_1`... id's are suppose to be unique.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add a `data-target` attribute to your button that would be the id of the `p` tag you want to slide up or down.

```
<p class="lead">
   <a data-target="#extra_1" class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" id="information_1" role="button">Show More Information</a>
</p>
<p id="extra_1" style="display: none;">extra information that may be less important, yet necesary</p>
```

But first you need to make sure you do not have duplicate ids, which you currently do... so fix that first. Also, `hidden` is not a valid value for the css `display` property... I think you mean `display: none;` (you are probably confused with `visibility: hidden;`)

Once you get you ids fix you can implement the following jquery for every section you want to toggle:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lead a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $(target).slideDown();
    });

    $('.lead a').on('dblclick', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $(target).slideUp();
    });
});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.lead a').on('click', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $(target).slideDown();
    });
    
    $('.lead a').on('dblclick', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();   
        var target = $(this).data('target');
        $(target).slideUp();
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-light text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4 ">5/<span class="text-primary">23</span>/18</h1>
  <p class="lead text-success p-0 m-0">PHP Arrays & Control Structures</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p><b>Loops & Structuring </b></p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" id="information_1" role="button" data-target="#extra_1">Show More Information</a>
  </p>
  <p id="extra_1" style="display: none;">extra information that may be less important, yet necesary</p>
</div>

<div class="jumbotron bg-dark text-light text-center">
  <h1 class="display-4 ">5/<span class="text-primary">24</span>/18</h1>
  <p class="lead text-success p-0 m-0">PHP Arrays & Control Structures</p>
  <hr class="my-4">
  <p><b>Loops & Structuring </b></p>
  <p class="lead">
    <a class="btn btn-outline-success btn-lg" id="information_2" role="button" data-target="#extra_2">Show More Information</a>
  </p>
  <p id="extra_2" style="display: none;">extra information that may be less important, yet necesary</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just starting as a web developer I appreciate the tips and tools.

Answer (score 1):

For starters, you have duplicate id's (for extra_1 and information_1) in your code. Never ever put duplicate ID's on the same page. I suspect you meant them to be unique, like extra_1, extra_2, and you want each of them opened/closed individually with the information button in the same jumbotron.

You could target elements using id attribute that starts with xxx `[id^="xxx"]`. For each button get the parent then next sibling.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('[id^="extra"]').hide(); // or use css to hide by default?

    $('[id^="information"]').dblclick(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().slideUp();
    });

    $('[id^="information"]').click(function(){
        $(this).parent().next().slideDown();
    });
});
```

Alternatively you could use class selectors, eg `.btn-outline-success` for the buttons.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I'm just starting as a web developer I appreciate the tips and tools.